What is the explanation of these special cases of tangents
The graph $y = |x|$ has no tangents at $x=0$ since it is not differentiable at that point, but it is possible to draw an infinite number of tangents to the graph at $x=0$, so why does it technically have no tangents?
Also for the graph of $y = x^3$, the tangent at $x=0$ is the $x$-axis, but the tangent cuts through the graph at that point.
What is the explanation of these two cases?

Wikipedia gives the following definition which is consistent with both of your examples: a straight line is tangent to the curve y = f(x) at a point x = c if the line passes through the point (c, f(c)) on the curve and has slope f'(c), where f' is the derivative of f.

The definition you're apparently trying to use is OK for a circle but it quickly runs into trouble for more general curves. The graph of $y=x^3$ doesn't have any lines that touch it in only one point and don't cross it.

I’m voting to close this question because you are taking calculus, where you will or should have seen that the definition of "tangent" involves the derivative, not the informal "touches the curve at just one point".

I understand that my knowledge on the matter was very limited. I am not a calculus student but a 10th grade student and I have only been introduced to the basic definition of a tangent and the graphs of certain functions.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... A better informal definition than "touches at one point" is this: A tangent line to a graph at a point is the unique line (if it exists) that the graph looks like when you zoom-in really-really-...-really close to the point. ... The problem with $y=|x|$ at $x=0$ is that graph always looks like a "V", not a single line, no matter how much you zoom-in; thus, the tangent is undefined at that point. There's no problem for $y=x^3$ at $x=0$, since there's nothing in the informal definition that bars a tangent from crossing the graph.

I understand now. Thank you @Blue for clarifying the matter. I have read up on the matter and now realize that, as you said, the slope of the tangent is equal to the derivative of the function at that point, as two points on the graph get infinitely close to each other it starts to look like a line. Thanks again for helping me.

You're not using the correct definition of tangent line. A tangent line is the best approximation to a curve at a given point by a straight line. There are two potential problems. There may be no such line or there may be more than one. In order to speak of the tangent line, it must be unique (exactly one)!
The usual way to think about this is to fix a point $x_0$ and consider the secant line that cuts the curve at $x_0$ and another varying point $x$. Then consider what happens to the line as $x$ collides with $x_0$. If this works (there's a particular line that we approach in this process), then it's the tangent line.
Nothing in this definition counts the number of times that the line intersects the curve.
In your examples, $y = |x|$ does not have a tangent line at $x = 0$ because it cannot be uniquely defined. From the right $(x > 0)$, it would have to have a slope of $1$ and from the left $(x < 0)$, it would have to have a slope of $-1$. This is an irresolvable contradiction. However, the cubic curve $y = x^3$ indeed has the tangent line $y = 0$ at the origin, as you can see by zooming in on the curve around that point.
